# ForEach loop for a Generic List repeated endlessly

Tags: c#, generics

After `Deserializing` a file with just one record

It seems that it's in an infinitive loop

```
IndexSeries = (List<string>)bFormatter.Deserialize(fsSeriesIndexGet);
IndexSeries.ForEach(name => AddSerie(name));
//IndexSeries.ForEach(delegate(String name)
//{
      //    AddSerie(name);
//});
```

`AddSerie` will be executed infinitively !

Comment: What is `AddSerie`, and what does it do?

Comment: Does `AddSerie` perhaps add an entry to `IndexSeries`?

Comment: It does not matter here, There is just one record and I expect that method to be executed just once, this foreach loop why is continuing endlessly ?

Comment: Even if it does, it should quickly hit OutOfMemory exception, unless, of course, AddSerie takes a long time to execute.

Comment: @Joey , Yes, I think you both pointed me to the problem, thanks, I'll check it, may fault

Comment: @user1096... reaching an OutOfMemory exception is hard if you do small allocations, have a 64-bit OS and a lot of disk space.

Comment: var list = new List<int> { 1 }; list.ForEach(i => list.Add(i)); //hits out of memory in a second on a 64bit os and machine with 3gb memory

Comment: +1 for all the participated friends, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I define:

```
//class level declaration (in a console app)
static List<string> strings;

static void Loop(string s)
{
  Console.WriteLine(s);
  strings.Add(s + "!");
}
```

Then

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  strings = new List<string> { "sample" };
  strings.ForEach(s => Console.WriteLine(s));
}
```

executes normally, outputing a single string, while

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  strings = new List<string> { "sample" };
  strings.ForEach(s => Loop(s));
}
```

loops indefinitely, adding '!'s in the process, and

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  strings = new List<string> { "sample" };
  foreach (string s in strings)
  {
    Loop(s);
  }
}
```

throws an InvalidOperationException (*Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute*), which, in my opinion is the correct behavior. Why the `List.ForEach` method allows the list to be changed by the action, I do not know, but would like to find out :)

Comment: I haven't looked at the code, but presumably it doesn't used `GetEnumerator` but iterates manually.

Comment: Thanks again, there shouldn't be any real issue, just a silly mistake, also thanks for the useful information you provide

Comment: I've asked about this behavior as a separate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9311730/why-does-listt-foreach-allow-its-list-to-be-modified

Comment: At first I thought it should be my mistake, but it was a tricky part to think of, and maybe a real questionable part, glad for your question that you continued this

Answer (score 4):

You use ambiguous terms. Firstly you mention an infinite loop, and then mention that `AddSerie` will be executed 'infinitively' [sic]; based on this, I would think that the issue you're bringing up is not with `ForEach` going on and on forever (as implied/stated), but instead that `AddSerie` does something once that seems to be taking forever.

This could even amount to something mentioned by Joey: if you're adding an element to a list *while* within the context of a `ForEach` call, then you're always one step behind in completion, and hence won't 'complete'. However, getting an `OutOfMemoryException` would actually occur relatively quickly *if*, say, `AddSerie` does nothing but that - it might take longer to get to such a point *if* `AddSerie` is a relatively time-consuming method. Then again, you might never get such an exception (in the context discussed) *if* `AddSerie` simply takes a dogs age to complete *without* contributing to the length of the list.

Showing your `AddSerie` code would be potentially most helpful in determining the *actual* issue.

Comment: All the participated friends were right,The type of Joey's question lead me to remember something I did in AddSerie that cause the collection always have plus one item, and the process will be continued that way.